# Could $\int\frac{1}{x^{N+1}(x-1)}dx$ be solved analytically?

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I am trying to solve this integral: 
$$\int\frac{1}{x^{N+1}(x-1)}dx$$
I have tried integration by partial fraction, substitution and by parts. But, I can't solve it. So, I would like to ask could this  be solved?
Also, May I know when partial fraction does not exist?

Thank you very much.

Update:
N is any number that is greater than 0. Sorry for forgetting to include such information, and apology for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that the integral *can* be solved analytically?

Comment: According to [W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%28x%5En+%28x-1%29%29+dx), there is a solution in terms of the hypergeometric function.  If you prefer, this can be written as a solution in terms of a power series.  However, the integral does not seem to have a closed form in the conventional sense.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I know when does the integral would look to have a closed form .

Comment: What is $N$? Also, are there limits, or are you only looking for a family of primitives?

Comment: Sorry, I should define N, I would update the question now.

Comment: Is $N$ any *real* number greater than $0$, or any *natural* number (i.e., integer) greater than $0$? The symbol $N$ is often, but not always, taken to mean the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Assuming that $N$ is natural, you may do the following

$$\int\frac{1}{x^{N+1}(x-1)}dx = \int\frac{1-x^{N+1}+x^{N+1}}{x^{N+1}(x-1)}dx$$
$$= -\int \frac 1{x^{N+1}}\sum_{n=0}^Nx^n \; dx + \int \frac{dx}{x-1}$$

The first sum comes from
$$\frac 1{x^{N+1}}\frac{1-x^{N+1}}{x-1}=-\frac 1{x^{N+1}}\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}=-\frac 1{x^{N+1}}(1+x+\cdots + x^N)$$

Basically, the above is the partial fraction decomposition of the integrand.

Answer (score 4):

If you try a few integer values of $N$, you'll notice that partial fraction decomposition gives you a pattern that suggests

$$\frac{1}{x^{N+1}(x-1)} = \frac{1}{x-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{N+1} \frac{1}{x^k}$$

From there, simply integrate both sides. They're fairly trivial integrals when rewritten as so.

Comment: Thank you very  much. I didn't notice this pattern.